# Json Decode and Parse Error node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, github, jzlib

Hi I'm trying to do this

```
const request = require('request');
const zlib = require('zlib');
const opts = {
    uri: 'http://data.githubarchive.org/2015-01-01-15.json.gz',
    encoding: null,
};

request.get(opts, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error) {
        zlib.gunzip(body, function(err, decoded) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                var json_string = decoded.toString('utf-8').replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, " ").trim();
                var json = JSON.parse(json_string);
                console.log("SJON", typeof json)
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I'm following the below steps:

1. fetching data from url
2. unzip that using **zlib.gunzip**
3. converting that decoded data to string
4. replacing all newline and beak statements
5. I'm trying to parse that string which throws error

I'm getting error while parsing data using `JSON.parse`, this is public `dataset` of **github**. I don't know where I'm going wrong, can any one help.

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? Have you tried printing out `json_string` before decoding it? Is it a valid JSON?

Comment: yes i printed thus string it is correct. i am getting parse error unexpected token at position   571. even i saved that string to file

Comment: Use a debugger (like `node-inspector`) to examine the contents of `json_string` before parsing. (Or in this case, `console.log` may be sufficient; normally a debugger is better, you get much better insight into what's happening.)

Comment: *"yes i printed thus string it is correct"* Almost certainly not. The `JSON.parse` in Node isn't broken. Show the string.

Answer (score 3):

That file contains one JSON object per line. Just removing the newlines won't yield a valid *single* JSON object. Instead, you can split the input data on newlines, and parse each line separately:

```
zlib.gunzip(body, function(err, decoded) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    let array = decoded.toString().trim().split(/\r?\n/).map(line => JSON.parse(line));
    ...
  }
});
```